# How to draw a buffer and calculate statistic based on map click with Leaflet R in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, maps, leaflet, buffer

Working code:

```
 ui <- shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
    leafletOutput("map")
    ))

    server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  ## Make your initial map
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      setView(lng = -86.779633, lat = 33.543682, zoom = 11) %>%
      addTiles(options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE))
  })

  ## Observe mouse click
  observeEvent(input$map_click, {
    ## Get the click info like had been doing
    click <- input$map_click
    clat <- click$lat
    clng <- click$lng
    address <- revgeocode(c(clng,clat))

    ## Add the marker to the map proxy
    leafletProxy('map') %>% # use the proxy to save computation
      addMarkers(lng=clng, lat=clat,
                 popup=address)
  })

})

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

I would like to enhance the code above by calculating a statistic within a 5000m buffer of the clicked address...everything I try does not work. Am I missing something?

```
  ui <- shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
      leafletOutput("map")
    ))

    server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    ## Make your initial map
      output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet() %>%
          setView(lng = -86.779633, lat = 33.543682, zoom = 11) %>%
          addTiles(options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE))
      })

      ## Observe mouse clicks and add circles
      observeEvent(input$map_click, {
        ## Get the click info like had been doing
        click <- input$map_click
        clat <- click$lat
        clng <- click$lng
        address <- revgeocode(c(clng,clat))
```

I want to create a SPDF of the lng and lat from the click:

```
coords<-c(clat, clng)


    crs <- "+init=epsg:26930" #' this is E Alabama 
    x_spdf <- spTransform(coords, CRSobj = crs)
```

Here I want to create a 5000m buffer around the clicked point

```
    b_dist <- 5*1000 

    buffer_spdf <- gBuffer(x_spdf, width=b_dist, byid=T)

    buffer <- gBuffer(x_spdf, width=b_dist)
```

This is my SPDF of office addresses I have on my computer that I want to convert to CRS for E Alabama

```
 dent_spdf <- spTransform(split_dentist, CRSobj = crs)
```

Identify # of offices within buffer

```
office_in_buffer <- split_office[!is.na(sp::over(split_office, buffer)),]
office_in_buffer <- spTransform(dent_in_office, CRS=crs)
```

Count # of offices in buffer

```
num_office <- nrow(office_in_buffer)
```

Calculate statistic based on # offices in buffer

```
expenditure <-office_in_buffer@data$variable/ (num_office + 1)

output$expenditure <- renderText(revenue) #' tell Shiny to display this number

leafletProxy('map') %>% # use the proxy to save computation
  addMarkers(lng=clng, lat=clat,
             popup=address)
  })

})

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```